# How to detect similar values in an array?

Tags: php

Say I have a list of genres that looks something like:

```
$genres = array(
    'soul', 
    'soul jazz', 
    'blues', 
    'jazz blues', 
    'rock', 
    'indie', 
    'cool jazz', 
    'rock-blues');
```

...And so on, for 762 values. How can I organize these genres into categories?

For example, I would want the Blues category to contain 'blues', 'jazz blues', and 'rock blues.' I would want the Jazz category to contain 'soul jazz', 'jazz blues', and 'cool jazz.'

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you get this array? Is this from a database?

Comment: Sounds like you want to represent a hierarchy.

Comment: @Machavity: From an API.

Comment: Mike which was the problem with similar_text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_match` would be one the best ways to solve your problem.

```
<?php
$categories = array("blues", "jazz");
$genres = array("soul", "soul jazz", "blues", "jazz blues", "rock", "indie", "cool jazz", "rock-blues");
$arr = array();
$others = array();
foreach($genres as $genre){
$num = 0;
    foreach($categories as $category){
        if(preg_match("/\\b".$category."\\b/", $genre)){
        $arr[$category][] = $genre;
        $num = 1;
        }
    }
    if($num == 0){
    $others[] = $genre;
    }
}
ksort($arr);
$arr["others"] = $others;
unset($genre, $num, $category, $others);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [blues] => Array
        (
            [0] => blues
            [1] => jazz blues
            [2] => rock-blues
        )

    [jazz] => Array
        (
            [0] => soul jazz
            [1] => jazz blues
            [2] => cool jazz
        )

    [others] => Array
        (
            [0] => soul
            [1] => rock
            [2] => indie
        )

)
```

Comment: As much as I dislike using regex, I actually got this one to work exactly how I desired. Thank you, Sharanya

Answer (score 1):

Given some seeds:

```
$seeds = array('blues','jazz',...);
```

Then just compute its nearest:

```
foreach($genres as $v) {
 $similarity = 0;
 $k = 0;
 foreach($seeds as $kk=>$vv) {
     $current = similar_text($v,$vv);
     if ($current>$similarity) {
        $similarity = $current;
        $k=$kk;
     }
  }
 $categories[$k][]=$v;

}
```

At this point you have your `$geners` labled in `$categories`;

```
Array
(
    [blues] => Array
        (
            [0] => soul
            [1] => blues
            [2] => jazz blues
            [3] => rock
            [4] => indie
            [5] => rock-blues
        )

    [jazz] => Array
        (
            [0] => soul jazz
            [1] => cool jazz
        )

)
```

Tested code at codepad: http://codepad.org/HCPcO4Iy

PS. clearly if you have those two seeds (blues and jeez) and then you have to cluster the genre "jeez blues" then it might be assigned to one or to the other without any logic

Comment: the solution is based on the `$similarity` level, and therefore, `clues` may get included in the `blues` category, which will be much dearer to this function than `jazz blues`

Comment: @Stoic: That is actually something I want. Testing this out now

Comment: @stoic: if that's the problem, you only need to use another function instead of similar_text to get the similarity that you want more...

Comment: @link: removed the downvote since OP states, he wants the same. probably, I misinterpreted the question. sorry, about that, and upvoted for reminding me about `similar_text` :)